# Getting current epoch time in seconds and milliseconds

Tags: c++, time

Using Arduino Yun.

My code:

```
time_t today;
time_t now;
...
void setup() {
  time(now);
...
  Serial.println( asctime(gmtime(&now)));
```

What I get is:

> Sat Jan 01 00:00:00 2000

I am expecting something like this:

> 1507572195.825

How do I get the number of seconds and milliseconds since the Linux Epoch?

Comment: I think that what you are looking for is the function `now();` which returns the current time as seconds since 1 Jan 1970. Read more about the [Arduino Time Library](https://playground.arduino.cc/Code/Time) .

Comment: [This](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/TimeCheck) may be of more interest - how to get the time from the Linux processor (which if you are online should be correct) rather than some random number the Arduino defaults to...

Comment: now(); is giving me the number of seconds from when the script started running rather than from Jan 1970.

Comment: Majenko - Getting very close. Using:
    if (!date.running()) {
    date.begin("date");
    date.addParameter("%s");
    date.run();
  }

I get seconds. How would I get seconds and a partial second like :1507586961.159

Comment: You may try `+%s.%N` as a parameter. On a standard Linux distro this gives seconds and nanoseconds. I have no Yun to test that though.

Comment: @Edgar Bonet:
Unfortunately %N does not return nanoseconds on the Yun. It just gets echoed back like it is text %N. Using +%s.%N get me 1234567890.%N